# Backbone view event handling lost after first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, event-handling

I am fairly new to javascript and have a simple page which displays a shopping cart summary in the top right corner.

[image: Before click]

When the update button is clicked the first time, the collection and view are updated as expected.

[image: After first click]

However, subsequent clicks have no effect and there is no errors in the console. The event handling appears to be lost after the first click.

I have noticed other similar problems posted on SO which point to the solution of invoking delegateEvents on the view object after .html() has been invoked. I have tried this but it has made no difference.

My backbone view is:

```
MyApp.View.Item = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
        'click #update-btn' : 'update',
        'click #reset-btn' : 'reset'
     }, 

     initialize: function(){
         console.log('item view initialize invoked');
         this.collection = new MyApp.Collection.Items();
         this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.display);
         var source = $("#cart-template").html();
         this.template = Handlebars.compile(source);
     },

     render: function(){
         console.log('render invoked');
         var html = this.template(this.collection);
         this.$el.html(html);
         // this.delegateEvents(); <-- Tried this
         return this;
    },

    display: function() {
        $('#cart-summary').html(this.render().el);
    },

    update: function(e) { 
        console.log('update invoked');
        e.preventDefault();
        var newItem = new MyApp.Model.Item();
        newItem.setName('blah');
        newItem.setPrice(20);
        this.collection.addItem(newItem);
    },  

    reset: function(e) { 
        console.log('reset invoked');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

My collection is

```
MyApp.Collection.Items = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    initialize: function(){
        this.items = 0;
        this.total = 0;
    },

    addItem: function(item) {
        console.log('addItem invoked');
        this.items++;
        this.total += item.getPrice();
        this.trigger('add');
   }

});
```

I am using backbone 1.1.2, jquery 2.1.1 and Chrome 35.0.1916.153.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure, perhaps assign a class rather than an id to the buttons and then modify your event selectors?

Comment: @RobSchmuecker Changed to use class selectors but no difference. Works for first click but not subsequent ones.

Comment: Can you perhaps make a fiddle ala http://jsfiddle.net/icoxfog417/pfxP5/

Comment: try delegating the events after the diplay has put the html back on the page. I suspect that your buttons are getting cleared in the rerender

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, when you are creating the view, you should set your el to #chart-summary.

```
MyApp.View.Item = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '#cart-summary'

    (your other stuff)
});
```

and try changing display function as follows

```
display: function() {
    this.render();
},
```

Comment: Brilliant, that's done the trick. Can you explain the difference here for a JS novice?

Comment: it's more backbone related than javascript.

1) backbone dom events are set after rendering for elements in your el.  
2) in your render function you do great job setting contents of your el. after completing your rendering, backbone sets your events again automatically.
3) however in display function you were removing contents of your el from DOM by setting $("cart-summary").html(...). and losing your event bindings.

Answer (score 0):

A tutorial example, http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-view/, uses the following line to make a new view:

var view = new MyApp.View.Item({ el: $("#'div container id, which contains button view'") });

I think it provides a refreshed view, where the buttons will act upon a click. I think it should be your last line of code in your backbone view. Perhaps you're already doing this, however I failed to see that in your code..